# Using a function inside class

Tags: c++, function, class, recursion

I have one class defined as example:

```
class Rectangle {
    int width, height;
  public:
    void set_values (int,int);
    int area (void);
} ;
```

Suppose that the area calculation is complex an in order to be clean and readable i want to use functions like `display_result();` or `order_items(int x, int y);`. How can i do this ? The general question is how to use functions inside classes in c++.

My particular case:

```
bool AlphaBetaAI::computeMove (PangScenario *ps, int playerNumber, int *move)
{
        int alpha=-Number_MAX_VALUE;
        int beta= Number_MAX_VALUE;
        float childValue;
        int score;

        vector<int> legalMovements;
        legalMovements.push_back(1); //Move right
        legalMovements.push_back(2); //Move left
        legalMovements.push_back(3); //stop
        legalMovements.push_back(4); //Shoot

        vector< pair<float,int> > lista;

        PangScenario *pangCopy = new PangScenario(*ps);

        //score=myPacman->getPoints(); Si quiero arrastrar los puntos ya conseguidos por pacman antes de tomar decision
        score=0; //Si quiero empezar desde 0 a partir del momento que calculo la decisión.

        lista.clear();

        for ( int i=0; i < legalMovements.size();i++)
            {
                if ( legalMovements[i] != 0)
                {
                    switch (legalMovements[i])
                    {
                        case 1: //North
                                pangCopy->characterPlayerOne->moveRight();
                                childValue = minimaxAlphaBeta(pangCopy, alpha, beta, score, 1, depth-1, jugador+1);
                                lista.push_back(make_pair(childValue,1));
                                break;
                        case 2: //South
                                CharactersLocationsMaze[playerRow]=sr+1;
                                CharactersLocationsMaze[playerColumn]=sc;
                                childValue= minimaxAlphaBeta(mazeTemp,CharactersLocationsMaze, alpha, beta, score, 2, depth-1, jugador+1);
                                lista.push_back(make_pair(childValue,2));
                                break;
                        case 3: //West
                                CharactersLocationsMaze[playerRow]=sr;
                                CharactersLocationsMaze[playerColumn]=sc-1;
                                childValue= minimaxAlphaBeta(mazeTemp,CharactersLocationsMaze, alpha, beta, score, 3, depth-1, jugador+1);
                                lista.push_back(make_pair(childValue,3));
                                break;
                        case 4: //East
                                CharactersLocationsMaze[playerRow]=sr;
                                CharactersLocationsMaze[playerColumn]=sc+1;
                                childValue = minimaxAlphaBeta(mazeTemp,CharactersLocationsMaze, alpha, beta, score, 4, depth-1, jugador+1);
                                lista.push_back(make_pair(childValue,4));
                                break;
                        }

                }
            }//for

//more code not relevant to the question
    }
```

I compute the move of some kind of pang game. To calculate the best movement id have to call minimaxAlphabeta recursively using a depth of 5. So i have to declare and define minimaxAlphabeta and use it inside the class computemove.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Reduce your particular case to fit your first example. Make it a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your question is not about using methods but about optimizing heavy calculations.

Let take your `Rectangle` example:

```
class Rectangle {
    int width, height;
  public:
    void set_values (int,int);
    int area (void);
} ;
```

Supposing that calculating `area` is not that heavy, it may be done in the method itself and that is a clear, straight and easy example of method. However, if the calculation is complex, we need some optimization.

The simplest solution is to only calculate the area when it make sense, and not always. For this purpose, we could save a `boolean` indicating the need of updating the value:

```
class Rectangle {
    float width=0.0, height=0.0;
    bool area_to_update = true;
    float area_last_value = 0.0;
  public:
    void set_values (float, float);
    float area ();
} ;

float Rectangle::area()
{
    if (area_to_update)
    {
        // ... Make complex calculation here, save it to area_last_value
        area_to_update = with*height;
        // save that the area is now correct.
        area_to_update = false;
    }
    // return the new result
    return area_to_update;
}
```

By default, the value need to be updated, so the first call to `area` will trigger the calculation, and following calls will just return the same value until an update is required.

When any of the values is changed, the `area` require to update again:

```
void Rectangle::set_values(float w, float h)
{
    // ... Update values here
    bool value_changed = (w!=width || h!=height);
    width= w;
    height = h;
    // Check if the value has really changed, and set area to be updated.
    if ( value_changed) area_to_update = true;
}
```

Comment: No sorry for my bad english, i want to use functions inside a class. In the second example i concrete a little: i need to use a recursive minimax algotithm that has to be called inside the class, so how can i define and declare the minimax function...or if you have a big class to use functions as you do in the main. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: @EDUARDGUTIERREZPASCUAL: Sorry, but I don't get your point, what do you mean by "I want to use functions inside a class"?

Comment: you can see in my code i need to define and use minimaxAlphaBeta(mazeTemp,CharactersLocationsMaze, alpha, beta, score, 4, depth-1, jugador+1); inside class computeMove... In a main function i know how to do it but not in a class.

Comment: @EDUARDGUTIERREZPASCUAL: To me, it look like you have other misunderstandings of C++ classes: AlphaBetaAi is your class, computeMove is your function, like Rectangle is your class, area is your function. So once you have declared and defined Rectangle::minimaxAlphaBeta(...) you can use it everywhere.

Comment: @EDUARDGUTIERREZPASCUAL: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116940/c-questions-and-answers We may discuss there further.

Comment: i dont have enough permissions to chat...hangouts or maybe chat skype ??

Answer (score 0):

Using functions in a class is straightforward. Example:

```
class Foo
{
    int x;
public:
    void bar();
    void baz();
};

void Foo::bar()
{
    x = 3;
}

void Foo::baz()
{
    bar(); // inside another class function (of same class), you just call it
}

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    f.baz(); // outside you need an instance, call with dot
}
```

A note regarding the line

```
PangScenario *pangCopy = new PangScenario(*ps);
```

Please don't use `new`, a regular variable will suffice here,
since `pangCopy` presumably don't need to outlive `AlphaBetaAI::computeMove`.
Further, in that function, prefer to take `ps` by reference.